# ASP.NET Connection Pool Problem?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, sqldatareader, sqlconnection

I create SqlConnection objects in every Insert,Update,Delete and Select methods in asp.net web pages. Then i close the connection objects in finally block. But im not sure about this is a good way. Is this a problem about connection pool?

Do you have any recommendations about how to use SqlConnection and SqlDataReader objects for me?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting errors, or seeing leaks?

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting this error:
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

Is this about i create so many sqlconnection object. (I close every one)

Comment: If you are getting this error and you are sure you close every connection and datareader then you might want to check look for other possibilities why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing the connection in the finally block is what you want to do.  An alternative would be to use the [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28VS.80%29.aspx) statement.  Using will work with any object that implements iDisposable including sqlconnection and will call dispose on the object on completion regardless if there was an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you are definitely closing off your SQLConnection then I would also review your SQLDataReader and ensure you are closing those.